# apache + nginx ubuntu php system variables value not always same

Tags: apache, nginx, server, php-ini

In php.ini, I have `sys_temp_dir = "/tmp"` which is by default

In apache config I am setting it like

```
php_admin_value sys_temp_dir = /home/some_user/tmp
```

In my test file I am using it as

```
<?php
echo sys_get_temp_dir();
```

Output is :

```
attempt 1: /home/some_user/tmp
attempt 2: /home/some_user/tmp
attempt 3: /tmp
```

`Pattern is not always same /tmp can come in any attempt`

Please note: I am using apache2 + nginx and each attempt I am talking about is happening on the browser.

My question is why this strange thing happening on the server and how I can solve this.

Comment: When you execute the script in CLI, it should always return the value defined in php.ini. If you open it in your browser, then `php_admin_value` will be prioritized. I wasn't able to reproduce the behaviour you described.

Comment: @TomaszKasperczyk Yes It is almost impossible but still it is happening, if you want I can show you on a `url`

Comment: Why exactly are you using both apache and nginx together? Is the second one acting as a reverse proxy? Do you use nginx to serve static content and forward all PHP calls to apache (which runs on a different TCP port)?

Comment: I'm asking about it because if you're using a load balancer in front of apache and nginx, then the reason for this behaviour would be pretty obvious, but to determine that I need to know how exactly are both services configured. Besides, it'd be easier to reproduce this behaviour and examine the problem if I could configure the services similarly on my test server.

Comment: @TomaszKasperczyk I am using vestacp apache2+nginx+phpfastcgi I am not using a Load-Balancer on my instance also I think VestaCP uses Nginx for reverse proxy. Thank you for your Interest in this.

Comment: @PraveenKumar did you find a solution for this problem? I think i have the same https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72322823/problems-when-uploading-image-to-server-nginx-php-7-4-upload-err-no-tmp-dir-with